# Метод рендеринга Гуро, формулы

Tags: алгоритм, графика

Попытался разобраться в методе Гуро, но не могу понять значения переменных в формулах, искал в гугле уже, но всюду не приводится их смысл. Что бы не вырывать из контекста формулы прикрепляю две страницы из учебника
[image: гуро стр. 1]
[image: гуро стр. 2]

Поясните пожалуйста что это за переменные. И что значит освещенность в данном контексте, как это связать с цветом? Или есть какой-то учебник совсем для чайников ?

Comment: Судя по всему, вопрос на самом деле "что такое освещенность "? Это количество света, падающего на конкретную точку модели. 0 - если совсем темно, 1 - если совсем светло.

Comment: Да, спасибо, но еще формулы бы разобрать, потому что мне всё так же не понятно что, например, скрывается за K[d](n,l) или просто за K[a], это какой-то коэффициент отражения?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Прежде чем вдаваться в физический смысл формул - необходимо разобраться в трёх компонентах света - ambient, diffuse и specular.

по приведённым вами формулам:

`Ia` - ambient - фоновая мощность света, иначе говоря этот тот свет который материал воспринимает без рассеивания и зеркального отражения. Является постоянной величиной и не зависит от позиции ни объекта ни источника света.

`Ka` - ambient - показывает степень материала воспринимать фоновый свет.

`Kd` - diffuse (рассеивающая) составляющая материала - показывает степень материала воспринимать рассеивающий свет - тот свет который в зависимости от ориентации (нормали) поверхности и направления света рассеивается во все стороны равномерно.

`(n, l)` - скалярное произведение векторов `n` - нормали к касательной плоскости к поверхности и `l` - вектора идущего из источника света в произвольную точку на изображении - при `cos(n, l) == 1`  произведение `Kd * (n, l)` даст `Kd` что будет означать максимальную яркость диффузной компоненты материала в этой точке, и при `cos(n, l) = 0` наоборот, максимальную темноту соответствующего пикселя (или точки).

`Ks` - specular составляющая материала - свойство материала воспринимать зеркальный свет (например сталь отражает свет с неким блеском).

`(v, r)^p` - скалярное произведение между вектором отражённым от вектора света и видовым вектором (вектор идущий из позиции камеры в точку), в степени коеффициента фонга (p) - чем больше эта степень тем острее будет отражаться зеркальный свет - и аналогично с диффузным источником света когда угол между этими векторами 0 тоесть `cos 0 == 1` зеркальное освещение достигает своего максимума (иначе говоря видовой вектор совпадает с вектором отражающий свет) и минимума когда угол прямой или больше прямого `cos pi/2 == 0`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**p.s.** 
*специально не привожу вариант `cos(n, h)^p` который в вашем учебнике, так как обычно зеркальное отражение света зависит от направления взгляда `v` и отражённого от света вектора `r`, а там не ясно что имеется ввиду под векторами `n` и `h`.*

С помощью формул `11.1` и `11.2` вычисляется конечный цвет пикселя как сумма всех составляющих - в первом случае с учётом только эмбиентной и диффузных компонент, во втором с учётом всех трёх.

Важно заметить, что модель Гуро вычисляя значения цвета во всех вершина полигона и интерполируя по этим точкам остальные значения иногда может приводить к потере аккурантности всего изображения по сравнению с моделей фонга, который вычисляет конечный цвет во всех точках (пикселях) делая результат более аккуратным но засчёт значительно большого количества вычислений.